# Why reactstrap doesn't have same behavior like bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

```css
.backgroundImage {
    background: url("page_livraison1.png") , url("Route.png");
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.verticalNav {
 background-color: #000000BF;
 height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="verticalNav col-md-3"> </div>
<div class="backgroundImage col-md-9"> </div>
```

This is my code in bootstrap but when i want to do the same in react js with reactStrap i didn't get the same result ... 
here is my code in react

```css
import Background from '../img/page_livraison1.png';
import Background1 from '../img/route.png';

const bgImgStyle = {
  background: `url(${Background})`+','+`url(${Background1})`,
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  height:'100vh',
  backgroundPosition: 'bottom',
}
const sideBarStyle = {
  backgroundColor:'#000000BF',
  height:'100vh',
}

export default {sideBarStyle};
export default {bgImgStyle};
```

```html
<Row>
  <Col lg="3" md="3" sm="5" xs="6"> 
    <SideBar /> 
  </Col>
  <Col lg="9" md="9" sm="7" xs="6"> 
     <BgImg /> 
  </Col>
</Row>
```

I don't understand why the result isn't the same however i did exactly the same code ...

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG00P.png this is in reactstrap

and

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHVL2.png this is in bootstrap

Comment: And what is your bootstrap HTML ?

Comment: what do you mean? do you speak french by any chance ?

Comment: You are lucky, since it's an english website, i'll translate in english afterward. 

Aurais-tu le HTML de ton fichier bootstrap ?

Comment: d'accord j'avais bien compris mais je ne vois pas de quel fichier tu parles ? mon html est envoyer c'est 2 div avec 2 colonne une de 9 et l'autre de 3 c'est tout le bootstrap vient du cdn tandis qu'en react je l'ai installer en Cli npm commande sa répond a ta question ?

Comment: Translation: Ok, I've understood fine, I just don't understand of which file you are talking about. My HTML is 2 div with 2 col (1 of 9 and 1 of 3). Bootstrap is from a CDN and react is installed from npm. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes and No, I havn't seen that HTML before. But what surrounding theses elements ? It look like a problem with markup (Grid/Col/Row/etc)

Oui et non, je n'avais pas vue le HTML, mais j'aimerais surtout savoir c'est quoi le HTML autour de tout sa. Il semble y avoir un problème avec les éléments autour (Grid/Col/Row/etc)

Comment: <div style={ Style.bgImgStyle }/>                                                       
 <div style= { Style.sideBarStyle } /> here you go

Comment: I mean, you call that somewhere ? On a page ?

Comment: this is a class and i call her finally <Shipping/> just like this on my index.js i render it.

Comment: And that Shipping is home alone on that index between two <body> markup ?

Comment: alone : class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Shipping/>

      );
  }
}

Comment: so no body ? and your html verion is empty too?

Comment: No there is a body in index.html with a div it is the root of the application so it’s not necessary to add another body.

Comment: And that's exactly the same between reactStrap and regular bootstrap ?

Comment: Reactstrap is bootstrap lol that’s why it’s weird ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170149/discussion-between-nathan-marciano-and-jonathan-lafleur).

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer the problem was that i had 2 Col, and in this 2 col i had 2 div with just style like background image and height. 
When i imported my component it was like this.

```html
<div class="col-md-3> 
<div style="background-color:"black"; height:"100vh";> </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-9>
<div style="background-image:".png"; height:"100vh";> </div>
</div>
```

and the right thing to do is

```html
<div class="col-md-3" style="...."> </div>
<div class="col-md-9" style="...."> </div>
```

So finally i thought it was the same but two div with size column or two div with a div inner these divs is not the same thing that's why it wasn't the same behavior but i didn't understand however i fixed it like this.

Thank you

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking yesterday ;) Good you found !

Comment: Oh ok maybe what you said + sleep on it did that i understood hahha, thanks